# Hibernate `create` not dropping table on `5.4.15.Final` version

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I am using a `5.4.15.Final` version of hibernate. When I am running my application in create mode it is not dropped and create the tables. Is there any way I can do it? I remember I was able to do the same in older version(don't exactly remember the version). My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is below:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="output.record.batch.size">10</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source">metadata</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action">create</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.create_namespaces">true</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target">sql/executors_create.sql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am creating the sessionFactory object as below:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Test.class).buildSessionFactory();
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: So, do you use `hibernate.cfg.xml` or java based configuration now?

Comment: `new Configuration().configure()` will automatically load `hibernate.cfg.xml`. I have already added the statement on how I am creating `SessionFactory`